# Trying to install pecl Solr extension but it needs curl

Tags: curl, php, solr

When I try to install solr-beta:

pecl install solr-beta

I get this error:

pecl/solr requires PHP extension "curl"
No valid packages found
install failed

The thing is curl is already installed and it seems to be enable when I look at my phpinfo page.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem us you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what is mentioned in http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=17012&edit=1, pecl does not recognize php modules that were not statically compiled into php. So if you are using any shared libraries, pecl will ignore them.

Pecl also ignores your php.ini.

> The good news is there are still two easy ways to install  this if you
>   have curl as a shared extension:
>
> 1) pear install pecl/solr
>
> 2) pecl install -n solr

That should install solr php module. You will have to include the solr.so library by modifying the php.ini file.